# Is there a way to append a calculated field to Select()?

Tags: c#, iqueryable

Is there a way to add a field to an IQueryable (or List<> or whatever) without having to rewrite an entire "new {list, of, all, fields}".  I have a dynamic field who can have different formulas depending on the situation. Here's a basic example :

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<User> users = new List<User>();
users.Add(new User { FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar"} );
users.Add(new User { FirstName = "Bar", LastName = "Foo"} );
```

I would like to add a field later ( just before the output ) without removing or rewriting all the existing fields

```
var betterUser = users.Select(u => new { FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName });
```

This will only return FullName, but I want to keep FirstName and LastName.  In my real code, I have about 15 fields and about 1.2 billion rows that will be cleaned up before adding the last field so if I add all possible calculated fields directly to the model, the performance takes a serious hit.

Comment: Do you need all the existing properties to be at the top-level? For example, you could have `users.Select(u => new { FullName = ..., User = u })` and then still get at `u.FirstName`, `u.LastName` etc. That would work even if `u` were already an anonymous type.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I could live with having the default fields nested.  If there's no other "cleaner" way I'll do it like that, thanks.

Comment: The Daysy Shipton solution is no bad, but why don't you put a calculate field into User class? Or an User class extension like public string FullName {get {return FirstName + LastName;}}

Comment: There's no way of creating an anonymous type that has all the existing properties of another type but with some extra ones, no. Do you want me to add this as an answer?

Comment: is it linq to sql?

Comment: (Scratch that offer - I can't write it up as an answer now anyway: I'm late for dinner. If anyone else wants to though, please go ahead :)

Comment: @GianlucaConte I can't really add the calculated field in the class or an extension since I won't know what will the formula until the middle of the function.  In my example, let's say that instead of a FullName I might need NameInitials. And yes, it's Linq to SQL.

Comment: Ok, can you create as many extension classes as the forumulas that you need?

Comment: @GianlucaConte I could, you propose I recast the class before the final output?  I tried but seems to lose its link to the DBContext and calculates itself instead of passing it in the SQL Query.

Comment: Is there a set of fields that can determine the type? Or better which rule to use? you may use a factory pattern. You could call ToString() to be free from linq to sql and paginate the query.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public object dynamicField {get; set;}
}


List<User> users = new List<User>();
users.Add(new User { FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar"} );
users.Add(new User { FirstName = "Bar", LastName = "Foo"} );

foreach (var obj in users)
{
  obj.dynamicField = obj.FirstName + " " + obj.LastName;
}
```

This way you would not have to remove or rewrite all the existing fields.

Comment: It could work, but I'm not sure if it's quick enough to process all rows in an acceptable time

Comment: It is O(n) operation, I don't believe you could do any better than this since you will have to iterate through the whole list to calculate the dynamic field's value. Using this way you don't have to initialise any new object and assign all to the property to it, you just calculate the dynamic field on the existing objects only.

Answer (score 1):

Your user class needs a property to do this: but you can do it:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasLegs { get; set; }
    public bool IsFoo { get; set; }
    public string FooLegs { get; set; }
}

private static string legsString(bool hasLegs)
    {
        return hasLegs ? "Has Legs" : "Has No Legs";
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>()
        {
            new Animal()
            {
                Name = "Foo",
                HasLegs = true
            },
            new Animal()
            {
                Name = "Kangaroo",
                HasLegs = true
            },
            new Animal()
            {
                Name = "Snake",
                HasLegs = false
            }

        };

        var fooAnimals = animals.Select(s => new Animal
        {
            Name = s.Name,
            HasLegs = s.HasLegs,
            IsFoo = (s.Name == "Foo" && s.HasLegs),
            FooLegs = $"{s.Name} {legsString(s.HasLegs)}"
        }).AsQueryable<Animal>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing all the new Animal in each case.  Just adding IsFoo in your example.

Comment: That's in the query only... Why would you need to write all new objects? Just add the property and it would be null unless your query calculated something new

Comment: I want to avoid rewriting the entire list of fields in the Select().  I have about 15 fields and would like to add one or two different calculated fields depending on the situation.  I could do it like that but I find it's not a clean way to do it.  Daisy's way is cleaner.

Comment: Daisy's way might be cleaner... But also inherently dangerous since the type is anonymous. YMMV but I'd spend the extra 10 minutes now for the safety later